# upload file with unicode filename

Tags: python, django

I have a file with a unicode name(eg chinese characters).  I get a UnicodeEncodeError.  I'm using postgres database with utf8 and the django development server on ubuntu lucid 64.  What am I missing?  I do the following where filename is the unicode name of the file in models.py:

```
def get_upload_path(instance,filename):
    return filename # Unicode error if filename has non latin 1 characters

class Kind (models.Model):
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style)
    kind_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

from shell:

[image]

Comment: What line are you getting the exception on? I'm reasonably certain it's on your `slugify` call.

Comment: i added some details into the code example.  slugify works, but when i try to concat the two strings together it doesn't work

Comment: This should help you understand what's going on under the hood: http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your string formatting. In python2, it automatically converts between `str` type (which is a series of bytes) and `unicode` type, which represents the abstract series of unicode codepoints.

I'm assuming that your `filename` is of type `unicode`.

`"tmp/%s/%s"` is a byte string, so python will try to automatically *encode* your `unicode` into `str` to match. The problem is that it uses the `ascii` encoding to do so, which can't hold your data.

Changing your `return` statement to use `temp2` instead of `filename` should work, since now you're using the right types together.

---

For the future, I'd also recommend watching the presentation I linked to in the comments, as it provides several strategies for avoiding this class of problem. The main one is that you should **only use bytes when sending data outside your program**. As soon as you receive bytes from the outside world, `decode` them to unicode, and only `encode` when you're sending the data out of your program. You should also use unicode string literals internally (`u""` instead of `""`).

I'd also recommend more meaningful variable names than `tempN`.

Comment: thanks for your help.  i went through the unicode presentation and it made sense out of this, but things are still not working. filename is already of type unicode.  even if i return just filename it still gives me django unicode error.  any ideas?

Comment: It's possible that django wants a `str` as your return value. The documentation for `FileField` does not specify what type your return value should be, it just says "a unix-style path".

Comment: i tried to convert it first to a byte string with .encode('utf-8') but then i get error 'DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-3: invalid data. You passed in "'\xe5\\x84\\xb7\xe5\\xae\\x8b Pro.ttf'" (<type 'str'>)'

Comment: There's got to be something else going on. If I do `"'\xe5\\x84\\xb7\xe5\\xae\\x8b Pro.ttf'".decode('utf-8')` I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 1: invalid continuation byte`, which means that byte sequence is not valid utf8

Comment: i see the there is a missing backlash for xe5, not sure why the first byte doesn't have the escape character.  thanks for your help.  i'm still trying with a shell

Comment: export LANG=en_US.utf-8; export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8;  #add these two lines in .bashrc to fix, but thought default ubuntu is utf8??

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with some helpful functions which you can use here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions

I think `smart_str` is what you need.

An alternative is to rename the files that are being uploaded by your users.